# How to edit fields in awk?

Tags: awk, sed, posix

for one of my university assignments I have to edit databases with POSIX utilities.

My problem is the following, I have been given a company import log and my professor wants me to get rid of the decimal seconds.

`2018-04-12 17:03:45,547 INFO:twoex.db.record_administration.utilities:`

I have tried using awk but since the timestamp is only one field, I am struggling to get rid of `,547`

Does anyone have an idea how I could tackle this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the first comma and everything that comes after it until a space or a tab is found (it is not clear to me what is the field separator):

```
sed 's/,[^ \t]*//' file
```

Result:

```
2018-04-12 17:03:45 INFO:twoex.db.record_administration.utilities:      # old line
2018-04-12 17:03:45,547 INFO:twoex.db.record_administration.utilities:  # new line
```